# Truncate MySQL table using Pandas+PyMySQL+SQLalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

Is there a way to truncate a table using pandas? I'm using a config.json to transfer the db config.

```
with open("config.json") as jsonfile:
    db_config = load(jsonfile)['database']
engine = create_engine(db_config['config'], echo = False)
```

```
{
    "database": {
        "config":"mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/some_db
    }
}
```

Like:

```
sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE some_db.some_table;"
pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=engine)
```

Error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return
> rows. It has been closed automatically

Comment: df.to_sql(pd.DataFrame(), if_exists='replace') ?

Comment: what's the issue with your current approach?

Comment: @Kulasangar ```sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.```

Comment: did you try checking here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5433

Comment: @Kulasangar it seems to be impossible =(